# PHP: Showing x to y out of z entries in paging

Tags: php

I would like to display values for "Showing `x` to `y` out of `z` entries" on a search result page, but I can't seem to get the math right.

Here are some of my variables:

```
// Total number of results
$total = mysqli_num_rows($rs);

// Items per page
$item_per_page = 3;

// Page number
$page_number = x;

// break records into pages
$total_pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0] / $item_per_page);

// get starting position to fetch the records
$page_position = (($page_number - 1) * $item_per_page);
```

Here's what I tried:

```
echo $page_position . ' to ' . ($page_position + $item_per_page) . ' out of ' . $total;
```

But let's say I have 11 records, displaying 3 on each page. On the 4th page there are only 2 results, but with my code above, it will say `"9 to 12 out of 11"`.

Can someone help me out with some formula to calculate number of entries shown on a given page?

Comment: Either you have 11 or 12 !!!

Comment: `min($page_position + $item_per_page, $total)`…?!

Comment: @deceze, Can you specify, please?

Comment: Your problem is that `$page_position + $item_per_page` obviously doesn't consider `$total` at all and may simply surpass it. Using `min` you can limit `$page_position + $item_per_page` to a maximum of `$total`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// For none-last page, $page_position should be
$page_position = (($page_number - 1) * $item_per_page) + 1;
// eg: Let's say $page_number = 1, then $page_position should be 1


// And for last page, there's sometimes the count of records not equal to the $item_per_page, so you should directly show the $total.
if ($page_number == $total_pages) {
    echo $page_position . ' to ' . $total . ' out of ' . $total;
}
```

Comment: Willis, it's working great for the last page, but how should it look like for the other pages?

Comment: or you can change altogher to one line with: echo $page_position . ' to ' . min($page_position + $item_per_page, $total) . ' out of ' . $total;

Comment: It works now for all pages except the first page. I'm displaying 3 items on each page, but on the first page it says `1 to 4`. But on the second page it's correct - it says `4 to 7`.

Comment: Sorry, the number after "to" should be min (($page_number  * $item_per_page) , $total)

Answer (score -1):

you may try something like this

```
    // Total number of results
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($rs);

    // Items per page
    $item_per_page = 3;

    // Page number
    $page_number = x;

    // break records into pages
    $total_pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0] / $item_per_page);

    // get starting position to fetch the records
    $page_position = (($page_number - 1) * $item_per_page);
    $remaining = $total_pages - ($page_position + $item_per_page);
    if ($remaining < $item_per_page){
      echo $page_position . ' to ' . ($total) . ' out of ' . $total;
    } else {
echo $page_position . ' to ' . ($page_position + $item_per_page) . ' out of ' . $total;
}
```

Comment: It's not quite working. On the first page it says: `0 to 11 out of 11`, on the next: `3 to 11 out of 11`, etc. - Like it's one behind...